# CodeIgniter Query Building

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I dont understand why this query is fetching only 1 row but there must be 34000 rows. No error generating. $fromDate = '2015-10-01', $toDate = '2015-10-31'
and $supervisorIdArray is a flatten array.

```
        $this->db->select('production.supervisor_id,production.employee_id,production.operation_id, SUM(production.quantity) as quantity,production_operation.operation_id,production_operation.rate');
        $this->db->from('production');
        $this->db->join('production_operation','production_operation.operation_id = production.operation_id', 'left');
        $this->db->where('production.production_date >=',$fromDate);
        $this->db->where('production.production_date <=',$toDate);
        $this->db->where_in('production.supervisor_id',$supervisorIdArray); 
        $this->db->order_by('production.supervisor_id','ASC');
        $this->db->order_by('production.employee_id','ASC');
        $this->db->order_by('production.operation_id','ASC');                    
        $query = $this->db->get();
        $Rows = $query->num_rows();
```

Comment: What is the resulting value of $query?

Comment: how many ids are in $supervisorIdArray

Comment: @toby-allen Maximum 451

Answer (score 2):

You are using a group function `SUM` thus it is resulting one rows. If you want many rows add `group by`

```
$this->db->group_by("production.supervisor_id");
```

Comment: Many thanks for the solution.

Comment: You are welcome @HafsulMaru